# Starting a video in picture in picture mode, while(!) opening a new window in javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-video, webapi

I'm trying to call the following two commands triggered from a button:

```
window.open('https://www.google.com/', '_blank');
await video.requestPictureInPicture();
```

But no matter how I try to call those functions, one will not work (on **mobile** devices)
My theory is that both commands require a user interaction and as the user provides only one interaction (button click), only one command will execute and the other will be blocked due to missing user interaction.

Anyone has an idea how it can be done?

Code sample can be found at:
https://codepen.io/eyalsi/pen/QWOqQRQ

Comment: According to most sources PIP is not supported on Android Mobile browsers but it should be on iOS and is not working, exactly as you say. From some examination it looks like the requestPictureinPicture method is simply not responding and also not returning any update to the promise (I added an error catch). If you can't see any obvious answer it may be worth raising a bug with iOS safari. If you do find an answer can you share here as it is an interesting problem!

Comment: Doesn't fully work on Windows Chrome. Only one (and first) option is allowed. So either I get a new window or I get the PIP small video box, but not both at same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the PiP request is being rejected because the original window looses focus before the API is called. If you postpone the new window opening then it works [demo](https://gerny.csb.app/pipDemo.html).

Code for ready reference:

```js
let status = '';
if (!('pictureInPictureEnabled' in document)) {
  status = '<span style="color:darkred;">The Picture-in-Picture API is not available.</span>'
} else if (!document.pictureInPictureEnabled) {
  status = '<span style="color:darkred;">The Picture-in-Picture API is disabled.</span>';
} else {
  status = '<span style="color:green">PiP available!</span>'
}
console.log(status);
stat.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<br>Status: ${status}`);

let pipWindow;
let log = console.log;
togglePipButton.addEventListener("click", async function(event) {
  log("Toggling Picture-in-Picture...");
  togglePipButton.disabled = true;
  try {

    // enqueue the task in message queue     <-- fix
    setTimeout(() => {
      log("opening window");
      window.open("https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/", "MDN");
    });

    if (video !== document.pictureInPictureElement) {
      log("requestPictureInPicture");
      let pipWindow = await video.requestPictureInPicture();
      await video.play();
    } else {
      await document.exitPictureInPicture();
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } finally {
    togglePipButton.disabled = false;
  }
});

// Note that this can happen if user clicked the "Toggle Picture-in-Picture"
// button but also if user clicked some browser context menu or if
// Picture-in-Picture was triggered automatically for instance.
video.addEventListener("enterpictureinpicture", function(event) {
  log("> Video entered Picture-in-Picture");

  pipWindow = event.pictureInPictureWindow;
  log(`> Window size is ${pipWindow.width}x${pipWindow.height}`);

  pipWindow.addEventListener("resize", onPipWindowResize);
});

video.addEventListener("leavepictureinpicture", function(event) {
  log("> Video left Picture-in-Picture");

  pipWindow.removeEventListener("resize", onPipWindowResize);
});

function onPipWindowResize(event) {
  log(`> Window size changed to ${pipWindow.width}x${pipWindow.height}`);
}

/* Feature support */

if ("pictureInPictureEnabled" in document) {
  // Set button ability depending on whether Picture-in-Picture can be used.
  setPipButton();
  video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", setPipButton);
  video.addEventListener("emptied", setPipButton);
} else {
  // Hide button if Picture-in-Picture is not supported.
  togglePipButton.hidden = true;
}

function setPipButton() {
  togglePipButton.disabled =
    video.readyState === 0 ||
    !document.pictureInPictureEnabled ||
    video.disablePictureInPicture;
}
```

```css
video {
  background: #1e2327;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 30%;
}

button {
  margin: 1rem 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<video id="video" controls playsinline src="https://storage.googleapis.com/media-session/caminandes/short.mp4" poster="https://storage.googleapis.com/media-session/caminandes/artwork-512.png"></video>
<br>
<button id="togglePipButton">Toggle PIP AND new window</button>
<div id="stat"></div>
<p>
  <br> Taken originally from:
  <a href="https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/picture-in-picture/">GoogleChrome/samples</a>
</p>
```

Or you can call `window.open()` in finally block after requesting PiP. Tested on Chrome 98 on Windows 10, and Safari 15.2 on iPad.

Note: code snippets on Stackoverflow can not open new popups/windows. For testing use the [demo](https://gerny.csb.app/pipDemo.html) link provided above.

Comment: Thanks! It seems like your idea/demo on iPhone, really works! 
(I actually tested it before with a 1 sec timeout - it seems to only works if it's 0 timeout!).
But it doesn't work for me on desktop - chrome or edge. At some point it did work on chrome, but than it stopped ( and show a popup block warning in the address bar), not sure what is the issue here.

Comment: @EyalS Popup being blocked is not related to our code. It's a browser's feature to stop websites from annoying us. Simply click on the warning and allow the popups. Or refer [this documentation](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95472?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop). It's working fine for me on Edge as well.

Comment: The thing is, that window.open is blocked on desktop, but only if I trigger requestPictureInPicture. 
window.open will work, if I won't. So it's not exactly the problem described in the link.
It's similar to calling window.open twice, one call after the other. Seems like the first succeeds and the second fails and blocked by the browser (and there's a good reason for that...)

Comment: If user hasn't blocked popups for our website, then we can open as many windows as we want in one go. But if user blocks it then all we can do is to request them to allow popups for the better experience.